# What is the meaning of "previous 12 months " in the clause below?

Tags: meaning, clauses, legalese, sentence-meaning

> for two years after separation of your employment, you shall
>   not solicit, entice away, offer employment, or employ directly or
>   indirectly (as employees, contractors, consultants), any employee,
>   subcontractor or other agents of "Company Name" who is then working
>   with "Company name" or who has worked with "Company Name" in the
>   previous 12 months

Does this mean that I can't offer a job to any person who left the "Company Name" but not completed one year if it is not 2 years since I left my job from "Company Name"?

Comment: I believe that it means he can't offer you employment for the next 2 years per his unemployment.
Also, if after 2 years he wants to give you an offer, you would have to have left "Company Name" for at least a year by that point.

Comment: Law.stockexchange.com might have some insight into this.

Comment: To me this is a clause that prevents you from hiring anyone from "Company name" that you currently work with or worked with in the past 12 months. This clause is valid for 2 years.

Comment: @BhoomikaArora What if the person joined after I left?

Comment: Then you haven't worked with them in the past 12 months and it should be outside this clause. The clause only mentions someone who you have worked with either currently or in the 12 months preceding the end of your  employment.

Comment: @BhoomikaArora Not so: the governing consideration is not whether the prospective employee worked with OP but whether the prospective employee had worked or is working with the company OP is leaving.

Comment: @StoneyB: I stand corrected. OP working with prospective employee is not a prerequisite. Just being in employment with the same employer either currently or in the 12 preceding months is sufficient to execute the clause.

Comment: I would naively interpret "previous 12 months" as counting back from the time you solicit them, or maybe the time of your separation. I don't think it refers to the time that the employment contract was signed.

Comment: But if this is a contract being signed at the time of separation, then the contract time and separation time are essentially the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means 12 months from date of contract ending. 
I.e. from when your contract of employment terminates.

So, anyone who works or has worked for them in the year preceding that event.

For law and interpretation, you may wish to check our legal sister site 
https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How will I transfer this question to law.stackexchange.com?

Comment: You can open a new question there and post a link to it here, if you wish.

Comment: _What_ date of contract? Or do you mean 'date of termination of your contract'?

Comment: Thanks @EdwinAshworth, tightened up my loose wording FYI.